# Define custom Navigation Property names in EF Database First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've been struggling with this for a couple years and never found a solution.

I have a table with multiple columns referencing to the same foreign table (`Result` table).

EF, to differentiate those relationships, names the navigation properties as follows:

```
public partial class MyTable
{
    public Nullable<int> ResultId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ResultSecondId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ResultThirdId { get; set; }

    public virtual Result Result { get; set; }
    public virtual Result Result1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Result Result2 { get; set; }
}
```

That means I have to know which one is which, and that something I don't want to do. I can't rename the navigation property in the designer because changes are made on the database and then the model is updated.

So, today I tried another approach. This is my code:

```
public partial class MyTable
{
    [ForeignKey("ResultSecondId")]
    public virtual Result ResultSecond{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ResultThirdId")]
    public virtual Result ResultThird { get; set; }
}
```

when I try to include this property:

```
context.MyTable.Include(x => x.ResultSecond)
```

I'm getting this error:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'MyModel.MyTable' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'ResultSecond'.

Is there any way that I can define the navigation property name outside the `.edmx`?

Comment: When using Database-first, you should rename the properties via the ***Designer Surface***, just right click on the property and choose ***Rename***. The designer will know how to do the rest, otherwise you need to modify the EDMX file manually, which I think is not easy.

Comment: But sometimes when I make changes on columns, like from Varchar(6) to Varchar(20) EF won't pick them up. So, instead of checking if all changes were applied I just delete all (Ctrl+A, delete, Update model)

Comment: well I was talking about renaming properties in your model. I don't think you can change the column's data type in your model and update back to database in database-first work-flow. In database first work-flow we always need a DBA to modify/manage the database. We do not have much right to touch the database. Of course if you are a single developer, you can go to the db manager system to change the database.